# Extracting text from highlighted annotations in a PDF file

Tags: python, qt, pdf, poppler

Since yesterday I'm trying to extract the text from some highlighted annotations in one pdf, using python-poppler-qt4.

According to [this documentation](http://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt4/classPoppler_1_1Page.html), looks like I have to get the text using the Page.text() method, passing a Rectangle argument from the higlighted annotation, which I get using Annotation.boundary(). But I get only blank text. Can someone help me? I copied my code below and added a link for the PDF I am using. Thanks for any help!

```
import popplerqt4
import sys
import PyQt4


def main():

    doc = popplerqt4.Poppler.Document.load(sys.argv[1])
    total_annotations = 0
    for i in range(doc.numPages()):
        page = doc.page(i)
        annotations = page.annotations()
        if len(annotations) > 0:
            for annotation in annotations:
                if  isinstance(annotation, popplerqt4.Poppler.Annotation):
                    total_annotations += 1
                    if(isinstance(annotation, popplerqt4.Poppler.HighlightAnnotation)):
                        print str(page.text(annotation.boundary()))
    if total_annotations > 0:
        print str(total_annotations) + " annotation(s) found"
    else:
        print "no annotations found"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Test pdf:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/10plnj67k9xd1ot/test.pdf

Answer (score 9):

Looking at [the documentation for Annotations](http://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt4/classPoppler_1_1Annotation.html#ab691c6b2fc90d2746465f2c6206d60ad) it seems that the boundary property *Returns this annotation's boundary rectangle in normalized coordinates.*  Although this seems a strange decision we can simply scale the coordinates by the `page.pageSize().width()` and `.height()` values.

```
import popplerqt4
import sys
import PyQt4


def main():

    doc = popplerqt4.Poppler.Document.load(sys.argv[1])
    total_annotations = 0
    for i in range(doc.numPages()):
        #print("========= PAGE {} =========".format(i+1))
        page = doc.page(i)
        annotations = page.annotations()
        (pwidth, pheight) = (page.pageSize().width(), page.pageSize().height())
        if len(annotations) > 0:
            for annotation in annotations:
                if  isinstance(annotation, popplerqt4.Poppler.Annotation):
                    total_annotations += 1
                    if(isinstance(annotation, popplerqt4.Poppler.HighlightAnnotation)):
                        quads = annotation.highlightQuads()
                        txt = ""
                        for quad in quads:
                            rect = (quad.points[0].x() * pwidth,
                                    quad.points[0].y() * pheight,
                                    quad.points[2].x() * pwidth,
                                    quad.points[2].y() * pheight)
                            bdy = PyQt4.QtCore.QRectF()
                            bdy.setCoords(*rect)
                            txt = txt + unicode(page.text(bdy)) + ' '

                        #print("========= ANNOTATION =========")
                        print(unicode(txt))

    if total_annotations > 0:
        print str(total_annotations) + " annotation(s) found"
    else:
        print "no annotations found"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Additionally, I decided to concatenate the `.highlightQuads()` to get a better representation of what was actually highlighted.

Please be aware of the explicit `<space>` I have appended to each quad region of text.

In the example document the returned `QString` could not be passed directly to `print()` or `str()`, the solution to this was to use `unicode()` instead.

I hope this helps someone as it helped me.

**Note:** Page rotation may affect the scaling values, I have not been able to test this.

Comment: Thanks, I struggled to install popplerqt4 but this worked like a charm!

Comment: Any good tutorial for installing poppler qt. I was having issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665100/python-poppler-qt4-installation-fails-unsupported-qt-version-5-6-2

Comment: This updated to extract the highlighted images https://gist.github.com/v-sukt/a59f549864d8369162a237e608251b07

Comment: If someone has issues with dependencies use docker images or Vagrant  at https://github.com/v-sukt/extract-pdf-notes