# Can I use python's pdfminer to extract highlights from a pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I wanted to try to extract highlighted text from a pdf, so I started looking at [pdfminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) but could not find any documentation for this specific function.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Hi! Did you found an answer or documentation?

Comment: Not pdfminer, but you might be interested in [How to extract Highlighted Parts from PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9099497/562769)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but please have a look at the script mentioned in [this](https://gist.github.com/stevepowell99/e1e389a57ea9a2bcb988) code listing.

Edit: I had to edit my answer because some wiser guys negatively graded my answer, I am trying to provide a solution to a problem that has had no answer for more than a year.

Comment: Thanks, I tried by could not get hold of pypoppler (see the error here https://gist.github.com/lambdamusic/b685596d492335838098)

Comment: I am actively looking for a solution for this issue
Poppler can be found here:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-poppler-qt4/  I can not find proper documentation. They send the reader to the C+ docs which are chinese to me :-) Currently looking for other Python solutions

Comment: Some clues here: http://poppler.freedesktop.narkive.com/7KbUnSay/python-pdf-hightlighted-text-not-annotation-popup-how-to-extract-it-text

and an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050551/extracting-text-from-higlighted-text-using-poppler-qt4-python-poppler-qt4

Comment: I got this to work, but unfortunately it does not extract highlights made with OSx Preview

Comment: Was it difficult to install Qt4 and poppler? I am at work and I could not test any of the above